# Экспоненциальное число чтение с файла с++

Tags: c++

как считать Экспоненициальную запись числа с файла ? ( подробнее желательно ) И в каком виде оно должно быть записано в файле?

Comment: Что такое *"экспоненциальное число"*? Может число с плавающей точкой? Так для этого есть пачка обычных функций в стандартной библиотеке.

Comment: Экспоненциальная запись числа  , немножко с формулировкой ошибся

Comment: Ок, что такое *"Экспоненциальная запись числа"*?

Comment: 0,0000000000123 = 1,23 x 10-11   это в математике в програмированиее 1,23E-11

Comment: И чем ваc `strtof` или анлоги не устраивают?

Comment: `double` в таком виде читается при помощи `iostream` [без проблем](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b710cbf3e95e6d3f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто берете и читайте как `double` при помощи `fstream`

```
#include <fstream>

//...

std::fstream fs ("test.txt");
double d;
fs >> d;
```

[Пример cin](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b710cbf3e95e6d3f), но разнцы никакой